# How to handle React Router Recursive Paths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a react app where I'm implementing file system like uploading files and creating folders etc (little dropbox). I was reading about react router recursive paths from this link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths
There component is being rendered on same page. I want to do that recursive pattern but rather than rerendering on same page, I want to only render latest route data just like when you work with file systems on some server like cpanel or dropbox. Any help would be appreciated.

App.js

```
    <Switch>
           <Route
           path={"/files/:title"} component={FolderDetail} />
   </Switch>
```

FolderDetail.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import UploadOptionsSidebar from "../components/Sidebar/UploadOptionsSidebar";
import BrowseFiles from "../components/BrowseFiles/BrowseFiles";
import CreateFolder from "../components/CreateFolder/CreateFolder";
import { AppContext } from "../components/Context/main";

const FolderDetail = ({ match, child }) => {
    const { files } = React.useContext(AppContext);
    const [createFolder, setCreateFolder] = useState(false);

    const getFiles = () => {
        return files.filter((file) => file.parent === match.params.title);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <React.Fragment>
                <h3>
                    Files >{" "}
                    <span className={"text-muted"}>{match.params.title}</span>{" "}
                </h3>
                <Row className={"mt-5 mx-0"}>
                    <Col md={"8"}>
                        <BrowseFiles files={getFiles()} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={"3"}>
                        <UploadOptionsSidebar
                            openCreateFolder={() => setCreateFolder(true)}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <CreateFolder
                    open={createFolder}
                    parent={match.params.title}
                    toggle={() => setCreateFolder(false)}
                />
            </React.Fragment>

            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path={`${match.url}/:title`}
                    render={() => <FolderDetail match={match} child={true} />}
                />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FolderDetail;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a non [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) path such as `<Route path="/files" component={Files} />` and using `this.props.location.pathname` (see [location docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)) in the `Files` component to extract the data you need from the path using a regular expression and only render what is needed to serve what your need (for example a view relative to the last part of the path)?